# Cannot select build to test with TestFlight on iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, cordova, app-store-connect, testflight

I built an app with [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/) (now commonly known as Cordova) that is already live on the app store, and I need to test it with Apple's [Test Flight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) because it started crashing inexplicably. However, when I go to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/login) and go to **[my app]->Test Flight->(my group of testers)->Builds->Add a build to start testing**, it will show me the version of the app but not the build itself - so there is nothing to select and proceed to testing.

Normally, I should see something like this:
[image]

But instead I see this:
[image]

If anyone knows what I can do to resolve this, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Got this answer from apple:

> I see that version 1.0.44 build 1.0.44 does not contain beta entitlements.
>
> To distribute a beta app to testers, you need to sign the app with a Distribution Provisioning profile that contains the beta entitlement. Distribution Provisioning profiles can be generated in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles portal.
>
> For more information on TestFlight Beta Testing, please refer to [iTunes Connect Developer Help](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/) or the [TestFlight Beta Testing tutorial video](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/overview#testflight-beta-testing).
>
> Should you have any further questions, you can email itunesconnect@apple.com or give us a call at any of our worldwide support numbers:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone
>
> Our hours of operation for telephone support are Mon-Fri, 9:00AM-7:00PM CST.